# Delete custom toolbar grayed out in ArcGIS 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

Recently I worked on adding a custom toolbar to ArcMap. It took a few tries, and now there are my initial 'drafts' of the toolbar still added to my ArcMap list of toolbars. According to the [help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00v00000000q000000), I should just be able to delete them. However, the Delete button is grayed out when I try to select my custom toolbar, as if it were one of the default toolbars. Has anyone else had this problem and come up with a solution?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution:

In the dropdown menu: Customize -> Add-In Manager...

And then, highlight add-in and click 'Delete this Add-In'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These are those strange situations where ArcGIS may have just locked itself. Have you tried closing all of your Arc products and then restart to see if you can delete? Maybe go as far as to do a restart of your computer to make sure all ArcGIS processes have been killed?

Comment: Sadly, this situation has persisted for months.

Comment: I figured as much. This is weird. I remember having the same issue a couple years ago and I know I resolved it, but I just can't rememeber how. I'll post up if it comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the dll for the toolbar or custom tool, try using ESRIRegAsm.exe,. It is located in the ~:\Program Files\Common Files\ArcGIS\bin folder. (OR c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\ArcGIS\bin)